# jquery add li to end of ul but last created li not recognised as last

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, click, live

I have the following code.  On cliking the button on the last li, I can create the new li.  However, once created, if I click on the latest button created, new li is created.  It seems it doesn`t recognise the last created li as the last li.  Can someone help on this please.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
```

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $("#mylist :button").click(function() {
                    var text = $(this).val();
                    if (text == "Save") {
                    }
                });

                $("#mylist li:last-child").click(function() {
                $(this).parent().append('<li>' + '<input type = "textbox">' + '<input type = "button" value= "Save">' + '</li>');

                });

            });

        </script>
```

```
<div>
<ul id="mylist">
<li id="1">1<button id="Button3">Delete</button> </li>    
<li id="2">2<button id="Button2">Delete</button></li>
<li id="3">3<button id="another_entry">Save</button></li> 
</ul>

<ul id="mylist2">
<li> test1 <button id="Button6">Delete</button></li>
<li> test2<button id="Button5">Delete</button> </li>
<li id="6"><button id="Button1">Delete</button></li> 
</ul>


</div>
```

Comment: I'd be more inclined to try and work out what on earth you're trying to achieve here if you ever accepted answers to your questions.

Comment: No one would like to help you if you don't even reward the one who answer... It's as easy as clicking the check on the right on your question page.

Comment: Also voting up isn't that hard.. It is our time, that you utilize, as a token of appreciation there is that up arrow.. :-D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `live` instead of `bind` as bind iterates elements **only once**, however `live` creates a **listener**, which attaches events dynamically, even to newly created elements.

You code should conform to this sample:

```
$("#mylist li:last-child")
    .live('click', function() {
        // append element
    });
```

tested with `jQuery 1.4.0`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
 $(this).parent().append('<li>'.........
```

Try

```
 $("#mylist").append('<li>'.........
```

Comment: this won't help, as OP stated, first click is functional, however second is not... so there is no problem in referencing `parent` element